# In MS Project 2010, how to avoid a task of being split by non working time?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, tasks, ms-project-2010

I am scheduling a series of 30 small training sessions (2,5d each), and I wish that each training would not be Split by weekends or holidays. All tasks are to be performed by the same person.

If training is scheduled to begin on a Friday, for instance, and to continue on Monday and Tuesday, I'd like to have it postponed to Monday.

Is there a way to automatically doing it?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of assumptions and feel free to adjust to your specific scenario.

If the sessions are 2.5 days each, they cannot start after 1:00 pm on Wed.  Create a calendar with working time Monday through Wednesday at 1:00 pm.  Make Wednesday after 1:00 pm all day Thursday, Friday, Saturday, and Sunday nonworking.  Make sure the calendar also has the standard holidays that you've included in the regular project calendar.

Create a 1 minute predecessor to the training sessions and assign the custom calendar to that task.  If the 1 minute predecessor falls outside the working time allowed for the sessions, it will be rescheduled to the next working day (Monday).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But case i have a Holiday on Tuesday, it looks like splitting will happen anyway.

Comment: If you have a Tuesday holiday and don't want the session to be split - you'll need to make that entire week non-working in the calendar for the "buffer" task.  If you don't want the event split and it takes 2.5 days - then it has to start either Monday, Tuesday, or by 1:00 pm Wednesday.  In the case of a Tuesday holiday, I'd make both Monday and Tuesday of those weeks non-working.  The event needs to start on Wednesday in that circumstance.